# What are some options for "catch you later" in both a figurative and a literal sense?

Tags: translation, word-choice

What are some options for "catch you later", as in either "to catch up with at a later time" (figurative sense) and in, for instance, a race, that is "to physically catch up with someone"?

I am looking to see if the meaning of this phrase is interchangeable in German as it is in English; and if not, what are the two most commonly used single words, verb or noun, in each case?

Comment: I didn't really understand your question in the first place. So I rephrased the question a bit. I hope that I got it right. If I'm wrong, feel free to rollback; or better: rephrase again to clarify. – I also removed the hint that you're using it for a story, because it didn't add any value to the question (or you need to give more context about the story; but the mere fact of writing a story isn't helpful)

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/?s=to+catch+up ... what's missing?

Comment: Off topic - die Frage behandelt keine dt. Phrase sondern eine englische. Wie kommt sowas hier hin?

Comment: @userunknown Er fragt nach möglichen Übertragungen der Phrase ins Deutsche, um zu vergleichen, ob diese vergleichbar sind (beispielsweise: Spricht man im Deutschen auch von "fangen"?). Daher ist das schon eine Frage, die hier hin gehört - sie klingt mir aber zu sehr nach "Könnt ihr mir das übersetzen".

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: `I am looking to see if the meaning of this phrase is interchangeable in German as it is in English` unterstellt, dies sei eine dt. Phrase, was es nicht ist. `Ich fang/greif Dich später` ist aber keine dt. Phrase. Oder sagt man etwas, was bildlich und wörtlich so übersetzt werden kann? `Ich sehe Dich später` ist ja bildlich etwas ganz anderes, oder? Was soll die Frage?

Answer (score 2):

There is no single word/phrase that expresses everything that *to catch up with someone* conveys.

- the meaning *to catch up with a friend*:
  (i.e. to meet them and tell them everything that happened since you last met them, as far as I understand the English phrase):
  There is no German phrase for that at all. We just say things like

  > Ich treffe mich am Abend mit Peter. Wir haben uns schon lange nicht mehr gesehen.

  to implicitly convey the intention to get back in touch with a friend you haven't seen in a while and might have neglected a bit.
- *catch you later* to end a conversation:
  (I don't have time to chat now, I'll call you at some later time)

  > Wir können später weiterreden.

  (we can continue our conversation at some later time) or

  > Ich ruf dich später an/zurück.

  might be appropriate, depending on context.
- the meaning of "to catch up with someone who is ahead of you in a race":
  You can either say

  > Jemanden einholen.

  or

  > Zu jemandem aufholen.

  Both of them mean that the person who had been behind is now near/next to/very close to the person that had been ahead in the race.

Comment: "Aufholen" kann in beiden Fällen angewandt werden. Im Rennen: "Er lag deutlich hinter her, aber hat ordentlich aufgeholt." – Beim Treffen: "Wir haben uns ewig nicht mehr gesehen. Ich denke, wir haben so einiges aufzuholen."

Comment: @Em1 Ja, aber die Formulierung "Wir haben einiges aufzuholen" kann nicht in der selben beiläufigen Art verwendet werden wie das englische *catch you later*. "Etwas aufzuholen haben" wird doch eher verwendet, wenn man jemanden längere Zeit ernsthaft vernachlässigt hat und ist jedenfalls nichts, das man an in einem einzelnen Gespräch/Treffen erledigen kann.

Comment: Ich habe auch *nachholen* in Erwägung gezogen, aber das funktioniert nur wenn ein geplantes/vereinbartes Treffen nicht stattfinden konnte oder eine der beteiligten Personen nicht teilnehmen konnte (im Sinne von "Wir sollten das unbedingt nachholen"). Und *nachholen* passt nicht im Kontext des Rennens.

Comment: Fair enough. Aber imho ist zwischen "catch you later" und "catch up with you later" ein Bedeutungsunterschied. Das eine meint nur soviel wie "see you later", das andere impliziert jedoch, dass man dann auf den neuesten Stand gebracht werden will. Imho–bin ja kein native English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

No, the meaning is not interchangeable in German. Actually, "catch you later" or "to catch up with s.o. (at a later time)" has no direct equivalent, the best I can think of is "sich (später) über jemanden auf den neuesten Stand bringen lassen". Depending on the context, you'd probably translate it in various ways.

"To catch up with s.o. in a race" is "jemanden einholen".

Answer (score -1):

Am I wrong in thinking that Bis Später or Bis Bald might do the job?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please avoid asking addtional/ same question as an answer. If the answers to this one does not answer your question, please open a new one, refer to this and describe what non-understanding is left over to you.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: [This post was not intended to be a real question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)

Comment: @Takkat: yes, this might be an answer written as an rhethorical question. No, I deny 100 % doubtlessness. Because this would require any hint that JKA knows the answer instead of having the same question and making a guess. The profile is empty, only one network, the answer is short as "one shot visits" usually are. So in case a recurring JKA rewrites it as an answer without questions etc. pp, I will not know for sure.